# Logical reads on empty target table when inserting into it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I am trying to figure out why logical reads are being performed on a target table when inserting into it when it is a blank table. I have the following table.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeID] [int] NOT NULL,
      [EmployeeName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [FG_Test]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

This is a blank table with ID being the primary key with a clustered index on that ID. When I use the following insert statement

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee];

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employee] WITH (TABLOCK) (EmployeeID, EmployeeName)
(
SELECT EmployeeID,
     EmployeeName
FROM Process.Employee
);
```

As per setting Statistics IO ON, I am getting 1596236 logical reads on the dbo.Employee table. When I then drop the index, these logic reads don't happen anymore, then when I read-add the exact same index the logical reads also do not occur anymore. In time the logical reads start again when I keep the index on the table.

Why would this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, logical reads are reported for the target table when the insert is not minimally logged.

These logical reads are associated with finding a place in the existing structure to add the new rows. Minimally-logged inserts use the bulk-loading mechanism, which allocates whole new pages/extents (and so does not need to read the target structure in the same way).

The variation you are seeing when inserting to a b-tree likely depends on whether the optimizer decides to sort rows into index key order (insert operator property `DMLRequestSort = true`), which can enable minimally-logged inserts if the target table is empty, or if [trace flag 610](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070.aspx) is enabled.